# Modifying the {default} beamer template to accept a footer image, and another .png on the title page

Tags: beamer, header-footer, templates

I'm a devotee of the `default` template, but I now work for an organization with a powerpoint template.  Obviously I am not going to use powerpoint, but I do need to make my beamer presentations look like their powerpoint template.  It is a simple template, and only requires a common footer image, as well as a disclaimer on the title slide, as well as an image in the upper left of the title slide.

If possible, I would like to simply add a few lines to the `default` beamer template to include a footer image, and an image an the upper left of the title page.

I have seen many threads that seek to make more complicated changes, along the lines of creating entirely new templates.  I wish to do something that is (hopefully) much simpler.  Would be grateful if anyone could show me how to do this.

I use ubuntu, and I've downloaded beamer from the standard texlive repositories that ship with ubuntu.

Modifying the content somewhat, here is an example of how the title page will have to look:
[image]

And here is how the rest of the slides will have to look:
[image]

And here are the images, as examples:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I won't use the white cat, it's scary!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{59Djv}%
}

\title{Title}
\author{author names}

\begin{document}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {
        \vskip-10pt
        We are not responsible for anything

      \leavevmode%
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{59Djv}%
    }

    \logo{%
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(-350,170){\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
        \end{picture}%
    }

    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
slide 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Maybe a simpler version, but less fine control over the titlepage image position:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{59Djv}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}{}

\title{Title}
\author{author names}

\begin{document}

{
    \addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \vskip-10pt
    We are not responsible for anything

    }{}

  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
slide 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was in a similar situation I used the `\logo` in combination with `tikz`:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\logo{% using the logo macro, the location of the logo is enforced by tikz
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt] at (current page.north east)%change the positioning here
        {\includegraphics[height=8mm]{img/logo.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

For the titleframe I used:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=1pt]%
        at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[height=5mm]{img/titlelogo.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does the logo text go in the header?

Comment: Yes the stuff from the first code snippet is in the document-preamble (so somewhere between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`). You'll have to adjust the `anchor=`, the `yshift=` and the `xshift=` keys and change the stuff in `(current page.north east)` to use the same you used for `anchor=`.